# Jupyter lab shortcuts

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've been using Jupyter Notebooks for a couple of years now. I've just headed over to Jupyter Lab, but I've found the lack of shortcuts to be a burden.

For example, I noticed that I can search for commands in the left hand palette. **But I can't seem to easily bind them to a keyboard shortcut. Is this even possible?**

For example, I want to collapse the current cell output with "O" and collapse all code cells with "Shift O".

[image]

Comment: Are you able to tune the JupyterLab to a more usable setting yet or are you still stick with NB

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This question is answered on GitHub [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4089).  You can also look [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/notebook-extension/src/index.ts#L224) for the correct `command` names to enter in your keyboard shortcut user overrides because they are not always the same as what is shown in the Commands side-bar.

The following are some that I use:

```js
{
  "shortcuts": [
    {
      "command": "notebook:hide-cell-outputs",
      "keys": [
        "O"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },    
    {
      "command": "notebook:show-cell-outputs",
      "keys": [
        "O", 
        "O"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },    

    {
      "command": "notebook:hide-all-cell-outputs",
      "keys": [
        "Ctrl L"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },

    {
      "command": "notebook:hide-all-cell-code",
      "keys": [
        "Shift O"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    }
  ]
}
```

which allows you to hide a cell output by pressing `O` once and showing the cell output by pressing `O` twice.  The last one collapses all cell code with `Shift + O` as you requested.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried this and it works, but it is somehow really slow. It takes over 1 second to collapse the cell output after pressing 'O'. Do you have any idea what may cause this? If I go to View -> Collapse Selected Output, it is instant. (I'm on macOS, if that matters at all)

Comment: Ah, I have found the reason why: The second shortcut uses O as well and therefore it is waiting to see whether a second O is typed. If I comment out the second keyboard shortcut, it works as expected.

Comment: Nice, things here, is there a code can do the hide-selected-cell-code?

Comment: @jeschwar: Is there a clean list of all the possible commands that one could include in the keyboard shortcut overrides? It seems strange that they don't have a master list there where you make the changes. Otherwise, how does one know the names of the commands?

Comment: @teepee: I look at the [source code](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/notebook-extension/src/index.ts#L70) to figure out which command names I need.  A master list would be useful but I find it's straight-forward to find what I need in that link.

Comment: Hi, @jeschwar, I copied your code and pasted in the User Preferences of the Settings in Jupyter lab but got this error `[additional property error] notebook: collpase-selected-outputs`. Do you happen to know why? Thanks

Comment: @Nemo From [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6865#issuecomment-565679065) "You need to format it so that there's one "shortcuts" list with several entries:".

Comment: Where can we find a list of command and selector to create our own shortcut?

Comment: I still come by and copy the setting.

Comment: How are you using this to customize shortcuts?

Answer (score 20):

On keyboards shortcuts of advance settings this code works fine for moving cells up and down

```
{
    // Move cell up
    "shortcuts": [
        {
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
      "command": "notebook:move-cell-up",
      "keys": [
        "Alt ArrowUp"
      ]
        },
    // Move cell down
        {
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
      "command": "notebook:move-cell-down",
      "keys": [
        "Alt ArrowDown"
      ]
    }
    ]

}
```

[image: move cell up and down]

Answer (score 9):

I use these settings to bind the actions to move a cell up/down to Ctrl + Up/Down:

```
{
    // Move cell up
    "notebook:move-cell-up": {
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
      "command": "notebook:move-cell-up",
      "keys": [
        "Ctrl ArrowUp"
      ]
    },

    // Move cell down
    "notebook:move-cell-down": {
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
      "command": "notebook:move-cell-down",
      "keys": [
        "Ctrl ArrowDown"
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

pX0r and plalanne's answers above combined worked for me with minor modification for Mac.

I hope this step-by-step iteration is helpful for someone like me who's a baby programmer. To summarize:

1. Open Advanced Settings Editor under the Settings tab, or `command ,` in Mac.
2. Navigate to Keyboard Shortcuts. You should see the screen plalanne answered with.
3. Use pX0r's codes, however making one change in the key binding as `Ctrl Arrowup` is reserved in Mac to view all running applications (if you have it set up that way). Similarly, `Shift Arrowup` is for selecting multiple cells. As a result, I opted for `Alt Arrowup`. Notice the key on your Mac keyboard says alt/option. You have to refer to it as `Alt` to work. There you have it. Copy the codes below to User Overrides which is the right pane.
4. Re-open your notebook and test if it works as intended.
5. You can customize more keys in this fashion as long as it is defined [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/notebook-extension/src/index.ts#L224) on GitHub. For the most part, all that you need are the command IDs starting line 72.

```
{
    // Move cell up
    "notebook:move-cell-up": {
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
      "command": "notebook:move-cell-up",
      "keys": [
        "Alt ArrowUp"
      ]
    },

    // Move cell down
    "notebook:move-cell-down": {
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
      "command": "notebook:move-cell-down",
      "keys": [
        "Alt ArrowDown"
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the settings file in Settings/Keyboard Shortcuts. Here :

[image: Jupyter lab keyboard shortcut]

There you can specify any custom shortcut that you would like!

Comment: Yeah, I saw this. But I think that the specific command I want isn't available.

Comment: Indeed. I managed to customize a few shortcuts, but couldn't find the command you're mentionning

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot save the "User Preferences" settings and get a syntax error

> [additional property error] command is not a valid property

you have probably missed to nest within the "shortcuts" list, as described [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6865). Additionally, to override an old setting you do the following, using Activate Next Tab and Activate Previous Tab as examples:

```
{
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "application:activate-next-tab",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Shift ]"
            ],
            "selector": "body",
            "disabled": true  // disable old setting
        },
        {
            "command": "application:activate-previous-tab",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Shift ["
            ],
            "selector": "body",
            "disabled": true  // disable old setting
        },
        {
            "command": "application:activate-next-tab",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl 1"  // enable new shortcut key
            ],
            "selector": "body"
        },
        {
            "command": "application:activate-previous-tab",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl 2"  // enable new shortcut key
            ],
            "selector": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you can click save and refresh your browser for the new setttings to take effect.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.