# How to import my keyboard shortcuts from jupyter-notebook to jupyter-lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am planning to switch from jupyter-notebook to jupyter-lab. But one of the things that is stopping me from doing so is the keyboard-shortcuts that use in notebook. I modified a lot of them in the notebook. Is there a way to import all my notebook config files to the jupyter-lab?

Also, the way shortcuts were edited in notebook were much more intuitive than how its done in jupyterlab. Is there any possibility to implement the similar interface for keyboard shortcut editing in jupyter lab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter lab shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280261/jupyter-lab-shortcuts)

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-shortcutui