# Jupyterlab can't map shortcuts: [additional property error]

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using Jupyterlab, 1.2.4. I tried the configuration below, but it gives an error. Any idea why?

[Jupyter lab shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280261/jupyter-lab-shortcuts)

[image: [additional property error] notebook:collapse-selected-outputs is not a valid property]

[image]

```json
{
  "notebook:collapse-selected-outputs": {
    "command": "notebook:hide-cell-outputs",
    "keys": [
      "O"
    ],
    "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
  },    

  "notebook:expand-selected-outputs": {
    "command": "notebook:show-cell-outputs",
    "keys": [
      "O", 
      "O"
    ],
    "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
  },    

  "notebook:clear-all-outputs": {
    "command": "notebook:hide-all-cell-outputs",
    "keys": [
      "Ctrl L"
    ],
    "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
  },

  "notebook:collapse-all-code": {
    "command": "notebook:hide-all-cell-code",
    "keys": [
      "Shift O"
    ],
    "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied the same JSON format that's used in the `System Defaults` section and everything works. Copy this to the `User Preferences` section.

```json
{
  "shortcuts": [
    {
      "command": "notebook:hide-cell-outputs",
      "keys": ["O"],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },
    {
      "command": "notebook:show-cell-outputs",
      "keys": ["O", "O"],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },
    {
      "command": "notebook:hide-all-cell-outputs",
      "keys": ["Ctrl L"],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },
    {
      "command": "notebook:hide-all-cell-code",
      "keys": ["Shift O"],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    }
  ]
}
```

Tested on JupyterLab 1.2.6.