# Why doesn't custom shortcut (to clear output in Jupyter Lab) work?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Following the [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280261/jupyter-lab-shortcuts) to create custom shortcuts in Jupyter Lab, I've got the **hide** and **show** work but not the one to **clear** cell output (the first command entry). Does anyone know what the issue is? Thank you!

```
{
  "shortcuts": [
    {
      "command": "notebook:clear-cell-outputs",
      "keys": [
        "Ctrl L"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },  

    {
      "command": "notebook:hide-cell-outputs",
      "keys": [
        "O"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },  

    {
      "command": "notebook:show-cell-outputs",
      "keys": [
        "Shift O"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command to use is `notebook:clear-cell-output` (no "s" at the end). The complete command list can be found [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/notebook-extension/src/index.ts#L224).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer the question. It seemed like a small error/inconsistency by the developers as there was a `s` in both `notebook:show-cell-outputs` and `notebook:show-all-cell-outputs`!